# Adjustable pushrod can be installed in new royal enfield classic 350?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, noise, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

My bike's tappet noise becomes much high after riding it for 4-5 kilometres so one of my mechanic told me to install adjustable pushrod which basically comes with royal enfield old models. 
My question is what should be done.
 Can my mechanic's suggestion solve tappet noise issue?

Comment: What year is your bike?

Comment: @DucatiKiller 2015

Comment: Shouldn't this still be under warranty? It should be within the time constraints, but possibly not the distance (2yr/20,000km). If it is, you should take it to the dealer and get it looked at.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  They are not accepting noise as problem but saying me that it happens in every   royal enfield bike and i think they are not that much educated about engine but just learners

Comment: The dealership is saying this to you? Is there a different dealership which you can take the bike to? Might be in the next town over, but you shouldn't be limited to where you usually take the bike. If it's still under warranty, you want to let the manufacturer fix it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  in my city there are two dealers with service station each but both are not taking seriously my bike's problem and just ignoring it. But now i am planning to take this problem to another city

Comment: When did Himalayan get pusrods? It has got an OHC engine and yes, even I'm looking forward to a set of adjustable pushrods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tappet noise is a "feature" provided in RE Classic 350. It doesn't do any harm as such, except for annoying the rider/owner of the bike.

To answer your question, Yes, it is possible to swap the tappet rods. RE recalled Himalayan few months ago to swap these tappet rods. Check with your service center to see if you can get the same tappet rods installed. Basically, they're longer than your usual tappet rods and they have a groove on them.